# Bin data within a group using breaks from another DF

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, cut

How to avoid using the for loop in the following code to speed up the computation (the real data is about 1e6 times larger)

```
id = rep(1:5, 20)
v = 1:100
df = data.frame(groupid = id, value = v)
df = dplyr::arrange(df, groupid)

bkt = rep(seq(0, 100, length.out = 4), 5)
id = rep(1:5, each = 4)
bktpts = data.frame(groupid = id, value = bkt)

for (i in 1:5) {
  df[df$groupid == i, "bin"] = cut(df[df$groupid == i, "value"],
                                   bktpts[bktpts$groupid == i, "value"],
                                   include.lowest = TRUE, labels = F)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came out with another `data.table` answer:

```
library(data.table) # load package

# set to data.table
setDT(df) 
setDT(bktpts)

# Make a join
df[bktpts[, list(.(value)), by = groupid], bks := V1, on = "groupid"]

# define the bins:
df[, bin := cut(value, bks[[1]], include.lowest = TRUE, labels = FALSE), by = groupid]

# remove the unneeded bks column
df[, bks := NULL]
```

Explaining the code:

`bktpts[, list(.(value)), by = groupid]` is a new table that has **in a list** al the values of `value` for each `groupid`. If you run it alone, you'll understand where we're going.

`bks := V1` assigns to variable `bks` in `df` whatever exists in `V1`, which is the name of the list column in the previous table. Of course `on = "groupid"` is the variable on which we make the join.

The code defining the bins needs little explanation, except by the `bks[[1]]` bit. It needs to be `[[` in order to access the list values and provide a vector, as required by the `cut` function.

**EDIT TO ADD:**

All data.table commands can be chained in a -rather unintelligible- single call:

```
df[bktpts[, list(.(value)), by = groupid], 
   bks := V1, 
   on = "groupid"][, 
                bin := cut(value, 
                           bks[[1]], 
                           include.lowest = TRUE, 
                           labels = FALSE), 
                by = groupid][, 
                             bks := NULL]
```

Comment: This version is definitely cleaner and more intuitive! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why yout `bktpts` is formatted like it is?

But here is a data.table slution that should be (at least a bit) faster than your for-loop.

```
library( data.table )

setDT(df)[ setDT(bktpts)[, `:=`( id = seq_len(.N),
                                 value_next = shift( value, type = "lead", fill = 99999999 ) ),
                         by = .(groupid) ],
           bin := i.id,
           on = .( groupid, value >= value, value < value_next ) ][]
```

Comment: I think bktpts is a good way to format it. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df); setDT(bktpts)

bktpts[, b := rowid(groupid) - 1L]
df[, b := bktpts[copy(.SD), on=.(groupid, value), roll = -Inf, x.b]]

# check result
df[, any(b != bin)]
# [1] FALSE
```

See `?data.table` for how rolling joins work.